# How to use timer.set in mongoose I want to use it like delay(1000);

Tags: timer, delay, iot, esp8266

This is how I did it in `arduino`

```
analogWrite(pin1,1023);
digitalWrite(pin2,HIGH);

delay(1500);

analogWrite(pin1,0);
digitalWrite(pin2,LOW);
```

How do I write the same code in js for mongoose os?

I want pin1 which is digital output to be low for 1000 ms and then high till the state.on changes

I tried using `timer.set` in mongoose os
pin2 is analog

```
function valveOC() {

    if (state.on === false) {

        Timer.set(1000, false, function() {

            GPIO.write(pin1, 0);

            PWM.set(pin2, 50, 100);

            print(value ? 'Tick' : 'Tock');
        }, null);

    }

    if (state.on === false) {
        Timer.set(1000, false, function() {

            GPIO.write(pin1, 1);
            PWM.set(pin2, 50, 100);

        }, null);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to know timer function in Mongoose OS:

Timer.set(milliseconds, repeat, handler)

Setup timer with milliseconds timeout and handler as a callback. If repeat is set to true, the call will be repeated indefinitely, otherwise it's a one-off.
Return value: numeric timer ID.

Equivalent of delay(1000) in Mongoose OS is :
Sys.usleep(microsecondes)

and your code will become:

```
if (state.on === false) {
        Sys.usleep(1000000);
        GPIO.write(pin1, 0);
        PWM.set(pin2, 50, 100):
}

if (state.on === false) {
        Sys.usleep(1000000);
        GPIO.write(pin1, 1);
        PWM.set(pin2, 50, 100);
}
```

You can see more details in [JS api documentation](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose-os/tree/master/docs/js-api)